# How to dynamically adjust PySpark parameters

Tags: variables, pyspark, sas, macros

coming from SAS I'm now working with PySpark. I still need to get used to it as handling macro variables here seems to be very different (is the right expression even "macro variables"?).

I have a date variable (or parameter) in YYYYMM format and want to define another parameter for the month ahead.

```
date = 202103
date_next = date + 1
```

Now, in SAS I would do the following

```
if substring(&date_next,5,2) = 13 then date_next = &date_next + 88
```

Fairly simple, but I don't know how to do this in PySpark. I sense that I don't even know the exact terminology for this issue as I can barely find any results by searching in Google.

Comment: Why are you storing the number 202,103 and calling it a date? Why not just create an actual date value? Normally when you want to use a date to represent a month you just use the first day of the month.

Comment: Doesn't PySpark have a mod function?  Your condition is just testing if mod(date,100) is 13.

Comment: Did you check the [Spark SQL functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html)?

Comment: Your posted SAS code is invalid.  It is treating the value of the macro variable DATE_NEXT as a character string in one place and as a number in another.  One or the other usage will cause SAS to autoconvert from character to numeric or numeric to character.